# 2d random walk on the nonnegative quadrant using martingale techniques

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, random-walk

I know the basics of (discrete time) martingales, and I'd appreciate any help and suggestions on how to prove the following *using martingale techniques*.

Let $Z_n$, $n\ge 0$ be a random walk on the nonnegative quadrant (i.e. $Z_n=(Z^{(1)}_n,Z^{(2)}_n)$ with $Z^{(1)}_n,Z^{(2)}_n\ge 0$) and
$$
P(Z_{n+1}=Z_n+(1,0)|\mathcal{F_n})=P(Z_{n+1}=Z_n+(0,1)|\mathcal{F_n})=1/2.
$$
Now let $\gamma$ be any path connecting neighboring lattice points and extending form the vertical axis to the horizontal axis. Let $X, Y$ be the number of steps (to the North and East, respectively) before hitting $\gamma$, and $S$ be the total number of steps until $\gamma$ is reached.

My objective is to show, *using martingale techniques*, that
$$
EX=EY=ES/2.
$$

EDIT

I followed the helpful hints below, and have solved it, assuming, additionaly, the following:

If $\gamma$ intersects the $x,y$ axes at $(0,b), (a,0)$, respectively, then $Z^{(1)}_0\le a, Z^{(2)}_n \le b$.

In this case, how can I rigorously prove that $S$ is bounded? It is intuitively clear that, if the path $\gamma$ is included in $[0,K]^2$, then $S\le 2K$. Or, as @Did pointed out below, there's the sharper bound of $\max\{x+y:(x,y)\in\gamma\}$. But, still, I'm looking for a rigorous proof that the range of $\{X_n\}$ indeed intersects $\gamma$.

Comment: I think I understand the problem, but I might be mistaken, since it seems to me that $S$ is a random variable, yet your equation at the end writes it as a number. But if I understand correctly, it looks like you can consider the process which increases by $1$ when you go north and decreases by $1$ when you go east. When adjoined to your termination condition, this forms a stopped martingale. At least if you are already between $\gamma$ and the axes, the optional stopping theorem applies because you are always approaching $\gamma$, and the longest path from any starting point to it is finite.

Comment: So you find that the expected value of the process I just described after $S$ steps is zero, from which your result follows. Your result seems rather trivially false if you are on the opposite side of $\gamma$ (for then you will never hit it).

Comment: Thanks a lot for both the correction and the suggestion!

Comment: Hint: $(Z^{(1)}_n-\frac12n)_{n\geqslant0}$ and $(Z^{(2)}_n-\frac12n)_{n\geqslant0}$ are martingales.

Comment: @Did Thank you for the very helpful comment, which enabled me to solve it, under the assumptions on $Z_0$ that I wrote above. But I couldn't prove rigorously that, under these assumptions, $S\le 2K$, although this is intuitively clear. I'd be grateful if you could help me construct a rigorous argument showing that the range of $\{X_n\}$ intersects the path $\gamma$.

Comment: Let $K=\max\{x+y\mid(x,y)\in\gamma\}$, then $Z$ meets $\gamma$ after at most $K$ steps.

Comment: @Did Thank you. This is very clear intuitively, but I'm having trouble producing a rigrorous proof. I'd appreciate if you could please tell me if it is straightforward to construct a complete, rigorous proof of this fact (preferrably an elementary one, without using the Jordan curve theorem)? Thanks so much!

Comment: No intuition needed here since $Z^{(1)}+Z^{(2)}$ increases by $1$ at each step.

Comment: @Did Sure, thanks. Still though... I can't see how to prove the existence of $n$ such that $Z_n\in \gamma.$ I'm sorry if this is easy and I'm bothering you, but if you could share a rigorous proof of the existence of an intersection point, that'd be great!

Comment: @Did If instead of a path, $\gamma$ were any simple curve extending from the $y$ to the $x$ axes, then I'm pretty sure we'd have to invoke the Jordan curve theorem. But in case it's a (simple) path, perhaps there's another, more elementary, proof.

Comment: If Z never meets gamma, there is a path linking (0,0) to infinity and never meeting gamma. I guess the description of gamma in your post excludes this.

Comment: @Did Thanks again! As you say, this scenario is impossible, but the only rigorous proof that I know of uses the Jordan curve theorem. Finding a simpler, rigorous, proof, pertaining specifically to paths on the lattice, is still bugging me though.

Comment: For every $n$, let $Y_n=\{y>Z^{(2)}_n\mid(Z^{(1)}_n,y)\in\gamma\}$. If $n>K=\max\{x+y\mid(x,y)\in\gamma\}$ then, for every $y>Z^{(2)}_n$, $Z^{(1)}_n+y>K$ hence $(Z^{(1)}_n,y)\notin\gamma$. This proves that $Y_n=\varnothing$ for $n$ large enough. Since $Y_0\ne\varnothing$, there exists $n$ such that $Y_{n-1}\ne\varnothing=Y_{n}$. I would look carefully at the possible configurations of $\gamma$, $Z_{n-1}$ and $Z_n$ at time $n$, to show that $Z_n\in\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks again @Did. To hit $\gamma$, it is necessary at th e previous step to hit $\gamma$ shifted one step either to the left or to the bottom. Now we can use strong induction on the total number of steps of $\gamma$.